# How to truncate decimal value in a text

Tags: android

So, I need to show a string in UI which has both numbers and text together.
Something like this,

`10.289 Mbps`

and I wanted to remove `.289` and just show `10 Mbps`

I tried a lot of options like setting text as

`String rounded = String.format("%.0f", speedValue);`

But nothing seems to be working for me.
Appreciate any help.

Comment: Cast to an int or long?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be possible in many ways.

1. Split String

   ```
   String inputStr = "10.289 Mbps";

   String[] splited = inputStr.split(" ");
   Double val = Double.parseDouble(splited[0]);
   System.out.println("Value : "+val.intValue()+" "+splited[1]);
   ```
2. Regx

   ```
   Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(([0-9]+)(.)?([0-9]+)?) ([A-Z,a-z]+)", Pattern.MULTILINE);
   Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(inputStr);
   if(matcher.find())
   {
       System.out.println("Value : "+matcher.group(2)+" "+matcher.group(5));
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

something like this can work:

```
string = "10.289 Mbps"
string_list = string.split(" ")
number = string_list[0]
number = float(number)
print(round(number))
```

basically isolate the number bu removing 'Mbps' then cast it to a float value and round it to get an integer.

Comment: this is in python but its the same concept for any language

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
String str = "10.289 Mbps";

String[] strArray = str.split(" ");
    
Long roundedValue = Math.round(Double.valueOf(strArray[0]));
    
String resultStr = roundedValue.toString() + " " + strArray[1];

System.out.println(resultStr);
```